# How to use your own custom ListItem template for Display, Edit, and New

Tags: development, custom, solution-package

I would like to use my own custom ListItem template. I also would like to overule the ListFieldIterator method to use some logica to include or exclude some fields dependance on user/usergroups:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543922%28v=office.12%29.aspx
http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2011/09/04/customizing-listitem-forms-using-renderingtemplates/

I have copied the default ListItem template and add it to my custom content template. All in custom code.

I have deploy my whole solutution and did some test. I go to my custom ListItem and created an item. It see the default listItem template. So something go's wrong.

Can someone give me some tips to check where the problem is?

In my custom code I create my custom list and custom content type. In my content type I have reference to my custom template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Item (0x01) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x0100839f032740084ac2ae6ea6ab45928a65"
               Name="CustomLogic"
               Group="CustomLogic"
               Description="CustomLogic"
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{427E04A8-45E5-4243-BFE9-5FDF6FC6205B}" Name="RFCState" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{EBC17A5D-F320-43D0-A275-7C657EA6F6C9}" Name="RFCDescription"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{76BF7D5B-6A12-48D1-9827-ADE990B03216}" Name="RFCCompany"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{9C9ED55A-7025-47F4-9637-27D5D2A1BCAE}" Name="RFCDepartment" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{87DA58EB-3C70-4EF4-B833-1D4A93D60AC9}" Name="RFCClient"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{56398822-7A4F-4155-A875-ADD09F32D4F2}" Name="RFCContact"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{A5A5CA1A-6CF4-4BA7-B650-7F06910EA0CD}" Name="RFCAppliesTo"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{47705F89-4883-4AD5-8495-98CE1D4B5C35}" Name="RFCDescriptionCurrent"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{F61E42BC-AEC0-43AA-9AD2-AD7B36C60B22}" Name="RFCDescriptionNew"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{97CD7687-4F16-4AC5-9156-1F178037B5D1}" Name="RFCRisks"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{D424D1B4-4CEA-4E47-B843-6B746EAD1E35}" Name="RFCDemands"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{09B7ED41-C5D0-4B8F-B102-F698164A05B9}" Name="RFCExpertise"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{F7788EA8-A6AD-4009-956A-E756E64D67CC}" Name="RFCImpactanalyses" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>

      <FieldRef ID="{1A64CE4A-716C-4572-B344-E7CCFE443D50}" Name="RFCScope"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{B131BD67-6B1E-4A40-A916-7C8D9CD17792}" Name="RFCExpectedEffort"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{39BC744E-08D4-410C-9D66-B728221634F5}" Name="RFCOperatingCosts"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{708B111D-F1B2-43BC-89B1-BDFF36C1DB4C}" Name="RFCMotivationAssessment"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{C95F5617-0C01-49F2-AA5C-8ADE757901F4}" Name="RFCPriority"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{D6E32A83-D6FD-431B-B2CB-625516D3935F}" Name="RFCDatePlanned"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>

      <FieldRef ID="{DB7133D3-96E6-48C5-8B69-76B208FFA5FD}" Name="RFCStatusChanged" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
    </FieldRefs>

    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>ListFormChangeManagement</Display>
          <Edit>ListFormChangeManagement</Edit>
          <New>ListFormChangeManagement</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

This is my custom template with a reference to my custom class with the ListFieldIterator overide method.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"   AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<%@Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="ApplicationPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WebControls"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SPHttpUtility" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBar" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBar.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBarButton" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBarButton.ascx" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="CustomOverrideControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92cf2084880c437e" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CustomOverrideControls" Assembly="CustomOverrideControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92cf2084880c437e" namespace="CustomOverrideControls"%>

<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate id="ListFormChangeManagement" runat="server">
    <Template>
        <span id='Span1'>
            <SharePoint:InformationBar runat="server"/>
            <div id="Div1">
            <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbltop" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                    <Template_RightButtons>
                        <SharePoint:NextPageButton runat="server"/>ssssss
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server"/>aaaaaf
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server"/>ffffffff
                    </Template_RightButtons>
            </wssuc:ToolBar>
            </div>
            <SharePoint:FormToolBar runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ItemValidationFailedMessage runat="server"/>
            <table class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <SharePoint:ChangeContentType runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:FolderFormFields runat="server"/>
            <%--<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator runat="server"/>--%>
            <CustomOverrideControls:CustomListFieldIterator runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ApprovalStatus runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:FormComponent TemplateName="AttachmentRows" runat="server"/>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td class="ms-formline"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='1' height='1' alt="" /></td></tr></table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding-top: 7px"><tr><td width="100%">
            <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ParentInformationField runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:InitContentType runat="server"/>
            <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbl" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                    <Template_Buttons>
                        <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo runat="server"/>
                        test1
                    </Template_Buttons>
                    <Template_RightButtons>
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server"/>test2
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server"/>test3
                    </Template_RightButtons>
                    test4
            </wssuc:ToolBar>
            </td></tr></table>
        </span>
        <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server"/>
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>

<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate id="ListForm" runat="server">
    <Template>
        <span id='part1'>
            <SharePoint:InformationBar ID="InformationBar1" runat="server"/>
            <div id="listFormToolBarTop">
            <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbltop" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                    <Template_RightButtons>
                        <SharePoint:NextPageButton runat="server"/>asdasd
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server"/>asdasd
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server"/>asdasd
                    </Template_RightButtons>
            </wssuc:ToolBar>
            </div>
            <SharePoint:FormToolBar ID="FormToolBar1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ItemValidationFailedMessage ID="ItemValidationFailedMessage1" runat="server"/>
            <table class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <SharePoint:ChangeContentType ID="ChangeContentType1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:FolderFormFields ID="FolderFormFields1" runat="server"/>
            <%--<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ID="ListFieldIterator1" runat="server"/>--%>
            <CustomOverrideControls:CustomListFieldIterator runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ApprovalStatus ID="ApprovalStatus1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:FormComponent ID="FormComponent1" TemplateName="AttachmentRows" runat="server"/>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td class="ms-formline"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='1' height='1' alt="" /></td></tr></table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding-top: 7px"><tr><td width="100%">
            <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion ID="ItemHiddenVersion1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ParentInformationField ID="ParentInformationField1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:InitContentType ID="InitContentType1" runat="server"/>
            <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbl" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                    <Template_Buttons>asdasd
                        <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo runat="server"/>
                    </Template_Buttons>asdasd
                    <Template_RightButtons>
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server"/>asdasd
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server"/>asdasd
                    </Template_RightButtons>asdasd
            </wssuc:ToolBar>asdasd
            </td></tr></table>asdasd
        </span>
        <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload ID="AttachmentUpload1" runat="server"/>
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have set `Inherits="True"` in your content type definition, SharePoint ignores your XmlDocuments section when the solution is deployed, therefore your content type after deployment has no reference to your custom form templates.

The problems with the Inherits attribute have been brought up many times, like [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/05/02/custom-content-types-and-inherits-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx), and [here](http://spboom.com/sharepoint-development/sharepoint-2010-content-type-inheritance-problems/), and many more places.

If you are willing to write a little code (and it seems like you are), I have developed a workaround for this problem, details can be found [on my blog](http://morefunthanapokeintheeye.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-successfully-publish-custom.html).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I have changed the Inherits boolean to False and deploy it to my sharepoint portal. I see some change now, but it is not yet what I am looking for. 

If I create a new item, I see 0 fields. Also ribon buttions are disabled.

Is it my CustomListFieldIterator ?? I have changed the code that it will always return true or false, but didnt help.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I do not have much experience creating custom form templates (yet - I am going to have to do some of that very soon).  I just noticed the problem with `Inherits`, and knew that your custom forms were being ignored.  Beyond that I don't know what to tell you, sorry.

Comment: Thats to bad. Otherwise thanks for your support. Is there someone else who can help me with my custom template?

Comment: This might help, I have had it bookmarked for a while to refer to when I eventually need to start customizing forms: [http://pioneeringsharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/11/correct-way-to-customize-forms.html](http://pioneeringsharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/11/correct-way-to-customize-forms.html)

Comment: I dont understand step 9, can you please explain?

Comment: It means go back to the ASCX file created in step 1, and register your assembly and a tag prefix associated with your assembly (the one that gets compiled when you build the project you're currently working in).  It looks like you've already done that with your lines `<%@ Assembly Name="CustomOverrideControls,....` and `<%@ Register TagPrefix="CustomOverrideControls"...`