# Custom listform template works in visual studio and development environment, but not after deploy on test enveronment?

Tags: custom, template

I have created a custom listform template with some logic. See also:
[How to use your own custom ListItem template for Display, Edit, and New](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58889/how-to-use-your-own-custom-listitem-template-for-display-edit-and-new)

I implemted also something like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543922%28v=office.12%29.aspx

In Visual studio debug I can see my custom listform template when I create a new item in my custom list. When I deploy it on the same dev server, I can also see my custom listitem template.

I have created a wsp and deploy it on my test environment. I activated all the features. But I do not see my custom listitem template when I click on new item of my custom list.

I have tryed also to create a new list instance of my custom list, but didnt help.

I have do an uninstall and remove, and then deploy the wsp again, but did als not work.

This is my custom listitem template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"   AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<%@Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="ApplicationPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WebControls"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SPHttpUtility" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBar" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBar.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBarButton" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBarButton.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="myCompany" Assembly="myCompany.ChangeManagement, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92cf2084880c437e"  Namespace="myCompany.ChangeManagement.Common" %>

<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate id="ListFormChangeManagement" runat="server">
    <Template>
        <span id='part1'>
        <div><h1>My Custom template</h1></div>
            <SharePoint:InformationBar ID="InformationBar1" runat="server"/>
            <div id="listFormToolBarTop">
            <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbltop" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                    <Template_RightButtons>
                        <SharePoint:NextPageButton ID="NextPageButton1" runat="server"/>
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton ID="SaveButton1" runat="server"/>
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton ID="GoBackButton1" runat="server"/>
                    </Template_RightButtons>
            </wssuc:ToolBar>
            </div>
            <SharePoint:FormToolBar ID="FormToolBar1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ItemValidationFailedMessage ID="ItemValidationFailedMessage1" runat="server"/>
            <table class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <SharePoint:ChangeContentType ID="ChangeContentType1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:FolderFormFields ID="FolderFormFields1" runat="server"/>
            <%--<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ID="ListFieldIterator1" runat="server"/>--%>
            <myCompany:ChangeManagementListFieldIterator ID="MyChangeManagementListFieldIterator" runat="server" />
            <SharePoint:ApprovalStatus ID="ApprovalStatus1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:FormComponent ID="FormComponent1" TemplateName="AttachmentRows" runat="server"/>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td class="ms-formline"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='1' height='1' alt="" /></td></tr></table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding-top: 7px"><tr><td width="100%">
            <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion ID="ItemHiddenVersion1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ParentInformationField ID="ParentInformationField1" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:InitContentType ID="InitContentType1" runat="server"/>
            <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbl" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                    <Template_Buttons>
                        <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo ID="CreatedModifiedInfo1" runat="server"/>
                    </Template_Buttons>
                    <Template_RightButtons>
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton ID="SaveButton2" runat="server"/>
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton ID="GoBackButton2" runat="server"/>
                    </Template_RightButtons>
            </wssuc:ToolBar>
            </td></tr></table>
        </span>
        <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload ID="AttachmentUpload1" runat="server"/>
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

This is my custom content type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Item (0x01) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x0100839f032740084ac2ae6ea6ab45928a65"
               Name="myCustomContentType"
               Group="myCompany CMP"
               Description="myCustomContentType"
               Inherits="FALSE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{427E04A8-45E5-4243-BFE9-5FDF6FC6205B}" Name="RFCState" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{EBC17A5D-F320-43D0-A275-7C657EA6F6C9}" Name="RFCDescription"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{76BF7D5B-6A12-48D1-9827-ADE990B03216}" Name="RFCCompany"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{9C9ED55A-7025-47F4-9637-27D5D2A1BCAE}" Name="RFCDepartment" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{87DA58EB-3C70-4EF4-B833-1D4A93D60AC9}" Name="RFCClient"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{56398822-7A4F-4155-A875-ADD09F32D4F2}" Name="RFCContact"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{A5A5CA1A-6CF4-4BA7-B650-7F06910EA0CD}" Name="RFCAppliesTo"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{47705F89-4883-4AD5-8495-98CE1D4B5C35}" Name="RFCDescriptionCurrent"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{F61E42BC-AEC0-43AA-9AD2-AD7B36C60B22}" Name="RFCDescriptionNew"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{97CD7687-4F16-4AC5-9156-1F178037B5D1}" Name="RFCRisks"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{D424D1B4-4CEA-4E47-B843-6B746EAD1E35}" Name="RFCDemands"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <!-- These are 5 fields only visible in edit mode-->
      <FieldRef ID="{09B7ED41-C5D0-4B8F-B102-F698164A05B9}" Name="RFCExpertise"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{1A64CE4A-716C-4572-B344-E7CCFE443D50}" Name="RFCScope"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{B131BD67-6B1E-4A40-A916-7C8D9CD17792}" Name="RFCExpectedEffort"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{39BC744E-08D4-410C-9D66-B728221634F5}" Name="RFCOperatingCosts"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{708B111D-F1B2-43BC-89B1-BDFF36C1DB4C}" Name="RFCMotivationAssessment"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{C95F5617-0C01-49F2-AA5C-8ADE757901F4}" Name="RFCPriority"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{D6E32A83-D6FD-431B-B2CB-625516D3935F}" Name="RFCDatePlanned"  ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>

      <FieldRef ID="{F7788EA8-A6AD-4009-956A-E756E64D67CC}" Name="RFCImpactanalyses" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{DB7133D3-96E6-48C5-8B69-76B208FFA5FD}" Name="RFCStatusChanged" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"/>
    </FieldRefs>

    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>ListFormChangeManagement</Display>
          <Edit>ListFormChangeManagement</Edit>
          <New>ListFormChangeManagement</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>

  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Comment: $ct = $w.ContentTypes["myCustomContentType"]
$ct.DisplayFormTemplateName

The value of this powershell commando is : ListForm. This is not what I am expecting. I am expecting my custom listform name: ListFormChangeManagement


What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem with a powershell commando, but I dont like it. If there is someone which has a better solution, please let me know:

```
 $w = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://mySPEnvironment"
 $ct = $w.ContentTypes["myCustomContentType"]
 $ct.DisplayFormTemplateName = "ListFormChangeManagement"
 $ct.EditFormTemplateName = "ListFormChangeManagement"
 $ct.NewFormTemplateName = "ListFormChangeManagement"
 $ct.Update($true)
```